# Get total sales of last 12 months even if values are null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following code in which it presently gives month wise Total Sales for current year, I need to get total sales from last month of previous year to current month of this year.

My query is as follows:

```
;WITH mcte AS (
 SELECT DATEADD(year, -1, getdate()) as MONTH_NAME
 UNION ALL
 SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,1,MONTH_NAME)
 FROM mcte
 WHERE DATEPART(MONTH,MONTH_NAME) < 12),octe AS(
 SELECT (DATENAME (MONTH, DATEADD ( MONTH, DATEPART(MONTH, OI.CreatedDate), -1) )) AS MONTH_NAME,
 SUM (OI.ItemQty * OI.TotalPrice) AS TOTAL_SALES
 FROM Order_Item OI            
 GROUP BY MONTH(OI.CreatedDate))
 SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,m.MONTH_NAME) + '' + DATENAME(YEAR,m.MONTH_NAME) as 
 MONTH_NAME, o.TOTAL_SALES FROM mcte m LEFT JOIN octe o ON o.MONTH_NAME = DATENAME(MONTH,m.MONTH_NAME)
```

and I am getting records

```
MONTH_NAME     TOTAL_SALES
July2019       54023.45
August2019     NULL
December2019   NULL
September2019  NULL
October2019    NULL
November2019   NULL
```

Here I am only getting data for previous year only, not getting data for current year.Can anyone please guide me on this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
DECLARE @CurDate DATE = GET_DATE()
DECLARE @OneYearPrior DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @CurDate)

WITH relevant_months(start_date, month_of_sale, year_of_sale) AS (
    SELECT 
        @CurDate AS start_date, 
        MONTH(@CurDate) as month_of_sale, 
        YEAR(@CurDate) as year_of_sale
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, -1, start_date) AS start_date,
        MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, start_date)) as month_of_sale, 
        YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, start_date)) AS year_of_sale
    FROM relevant_months
    WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, -1, start_date) >= @OneYearPrior
),
relevant_data AS (
    SELECT OI.CreatedDate, 
        OI.ItemQty, 
        OI.TotalPrice, 
        MONTH(OI.CreatedDate), AS month_of_sale, 
        YEAR(OI.CreatedDate) AS year_of_sale
    FROM Order_Item OI
    WHERE OI.CreatedDate >= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())
)
SELECT rm.month_of_sale as month, rm.year_of_sale as year, 
    SUM(rd.ItemQty*rd.TotalPrice) as total_sales
FROM relevant_months rm
LEFT JOIN relevant_data rd
    ON rm.month_of_sale = rd.month_of_sale
    AND rm.year_of_sale = rd.year_of_sale
GROUP BY rm.month_of_sale, rm.year_of_sale
ORDER BY rm.year_of_sale asc, rm.month_of_sale asc
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution , but here I also need other months including null values. its only displaying months which having values

Comment: @rbolling Sorry for late reply.Thank you very much for the solution , it works.. great..

Comment: @ANALKUKADIYA Great!

Answer (score 1):

You are only generating months up to 12.  Try replacing the first CTE with:

```
WITH mcte AS (
      SELECT DATEADD(year, -1, getdate()) as MONTH_NAME
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,1,MONTH_NAME)
      FROM mcte
      WHERE month_name < GETDATE()
     ),
```

Note the difference is the `WHERE` clause.

The entire query should look like this:

```
WITH months AS (
      SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(getdate()) - 1, MONTH(getdate()), 1) as month
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, month)
      FROM months
      WHERE EOMONTH(month) < GETDATE()
     )
SELECT m.month, SUM(OI.ItemQty * OI.TotalPrice) AS TOTAL_SALES
FROM months m LEFT JOIN
     Order_Item OI oi
     ON oi.CreatedDate >= m.month AND
        oi.CreatedDate < DATEAADD(month, 1, m.month)          
GROUP BY m.month
```

Comment: Sorry but its replicating total sales values with previous year month /current year month whichever giving null values

Comment: @ANALKUKADIYA . . . Lots of things need to be fixed.  Your question here is just about generating all the months -- not about getting a particular result set for a particular set of data.  That said, I added the query that you want.

Comment: Thank you for the solution , but Its giving me an error of"Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "month" of recursive query "mcte"."

Comment: @ANALKUKADIYA . . . I fixed the recursive CTE and it works:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cd2121d9b6eda7037cc24ea2d1a63d90.